# What does the following makefile command do? /no-symbols-control-file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, binaryfiles, contiki

I cam across the following command in a makefile:

```
%-nosyms.$(TARGET).elf: %.co $(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES) $(INTERRUPT_OBJECTFILES) contiki-$(TARGET).a
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(filter-out %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Source: [Contiki/cpu/arm/stm32f103/Makefile.stm32f103 .](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/cpu/arm/stm32f103/Makefile.stm32f103#L132-133)

Does this command generate no-symbols-control-file? What is the use of a no symbol image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece by piece analysis:

*The Makefile's target is:*

`%-nosyms.$(TARGET).elf`

*The list of prerequisites is:*

`%.co $(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES) $(INTERRUPT_OBJECTFILES) contiki-$(TARGET).a`

*The target recipe is:*

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(filter-out %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Makefile's logic is:

1. If `*-nosyms.$(TARGET).elf` file exists, compare the file's timestamp to that of *all* its pre-requisites. Rebuild this file (i.e., run the given recipe) if any of the pre-requisites is newer. If the target is marked as [`.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)) (seems not to be the case), rebuild without checking the timestamp.
2. Else, go to each prerequisite recipe and execute one by one (or in parallel if `-j` option provided to `make`):

   - `%.co`
   - `$(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES)`
   - `$(INTERRUPT_OBJECTFILES)`
   - `contiki-$(TARGET).a`
3. Then, handle the recipe for the current target, by calling:

`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(filter-out %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(LDFLAGS)`

Where:

- `$@`: the name of the current target (i.e. `*-nosyms.$(TARGET).elf`)
- `$^`: The list of prerequisites (i.e. `%.co $(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES) $(INTERRUPT_OBJECTFILES) contiki-$(TARGET).a`)
- `$(filter-out %.a,$^)`: the non-`*.a` files from the prerequisite list.
- `$(filter %.a,$^)`: the `*.a` files from the prerequisite list.

Comment: What does `$(filter-out %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^) $(filter %.a,$^)` do?

Comment: @darthspeedious: see the updated answer. The purpose of the `filter` and `filter-out` functions is to create a sorted list starting with the non-`*.a` and ending with `*.a` files. Though, I see no reason for using `$(filter %.a,$^)` twice.

Comment: I have added the source (in case it interests you). `.a` files are archives right? The image generated will not have libraries, is it so?

Comment: The `.a` files are the archives produced by [`ar`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar.html) program. Apparently, this Makefile generates an executable ELF image. The `*.a` files are going to be linked into this ELF image.

Comment: It generates 2 executables when i try to run it: `<project_name>.<target>` and `<project_name>-nosyms.<target>`, my question is what is the use of this other file.

Comment: Ok, so there are two executable ELF images. The one without `nosyms` is suitable for debug and tests. The one with `nosyms` should be suitable for a release (no debug symbols). The `nosyms` version should also be smaller in size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please elaborate a little more in your answer as to why does it have nosyms in its name.

Comment: Basically, the debug image (the one bigger in size) should have `-g` compiler flag enabled, compared to the `nosyms` one.

Comment: I cannot, i do not have stm32 mcu. I am trying to port contiki to lpc1347 so i was trying to understand the makefile.

Comment: To understand the differences between the images, study/compare the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in both cases and check the compiler/linker documentation on the info extracted from these flags.

Comment: Er, not quite. You say _If *-nosyms.$(TARGET).elf file exists, exit_. No. If this file exists, _make_ will compare its time to that of all its pre-requisites. _Make_ will rebuild this file (i.e., run the given recipe) if any of the pre-requisites is newer.

Comment: @bobbogo: you are right! I will update my answer with your permission.